# Solubility of thromboxane A2 agonist U-46619 in H2O

Tags: cell-biology

First of all, I'm not sure I can dissolve U-46619 in water so that's also part of the question.

***If*** it is soluble in water, how much can I dissolve before saturation?

***If not***, what's the right solvent to dissolve this agonist?